# MySQL Odd-Joining Issue

Tags: mysql

I *had* the following code:

```
select DB.T1.ID,
DB.T1.B,
DB.T1.C,
DB.T2.ID,
DB.T2.B,
DB.T2.R,
DB.T3.ID,
DB.T3.Q
DB.T1.DUP,
DB.T2.DUP,
DB.T3.DUP
from DB.T1, DB.T2, DB.T3
where DB.T1.id = DB.T2.ID
and DB.T1.id = DB.T3.ID
and DB.T2.id = DB.T3.id
and DB.T1.DUP = 'not_duplicate'
and DB.T2.DUP = 'not_duplicate'
and DB.T3.DUP = 'not_duplicate'
;
```

The output returned 0 rows, however.  So, I changed the values of the "DUP" column in each table from duplicate/not_duplicate instead to 0/1.  I tried this code and it worked:

```
select DB.T1.ID,
DB.T1.B,
DB.T1.C,
DB.T2.ID,
DB.T2.B,
DB.T2.R,
DB.T3.ID,
DB.T3.Q
DB.T1.DUP,
DB.T2.DUP,
DB.T3.DUP
from DB.T1, DB.T2, DB.T3
where DB.T1.id = DB.T2.ID
and DB.T1.id = DB.T3.ID
and DB.T2.id = DB.T3.id
and DB.T1.DUP = 1
and DB.T2.DUP = 1
and DB.T3.DUP = 1
;
```

The second code works perfectly, the first one returned 0 rows.  Does anyone know why was this happening?  The values "not_duplicate" and "duplicate" were the exact same strings as the csv's that I imported into the database from.  I can't explain why this would be the case and I'm really pretty curious.

Thanks very much!

Comment: What is the datatype of that column?

Comment: It's VARCHAR(255).  the "DUP" column is the last column in every row for each table if that makes any difference...

Comment: varchar but what are you storing in it? 1 or not_duplicate ?

Comment: Sorry if it was confusing. I was storing "duplicate" and "not_duplicate" initially, but because the joining script above was not producing what I wanted, I then changed it to store "1" or "0".  Does that make sense? I didn't know if the "_" somehow messed up MySQL so I tried "1" and "0" (both as varchar(255)).

Answer (score 0):

because the DUP column they dont have this `not_duplicate` in fields. they have 1
then it doesnt match your query .

the query returns values which are stored in the column DUP .

Comment: The thing I don't quite understand is why it registers "1" when I change the cell's values to "1", but it didn't seem to register "not_duplicate".

Comment: I didn't know if MySQL has a special way of treating the values in the last column in a row, adding a random byte to the end or something that would allow a "1" to be recognized but not "not_duplicate"...

Comment: if you use numbers , try to change to INT instead of varchar

Comment: The second code sample above works perfectly.  The fact that "1" is a varchar is not the issue.  That's what is kind of strange about this.  The only difference I can see is that in the first case my values in the "DUPLICATE" column were either "duplicate" or "not_duplicate."  In the second case, for the same exact datatype, the values were either "1" or "0".  In the first case the code did not work.  In the second case it did.  Something isn't adding up to me...

Comment: if you post your code where you save this value and your database , maybe we can see where your fault. this should work with dublicate word

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm beginning to think that MySQL Workbench is just super buggy. I had a similar issue today where when I want to see x rows that have a value of 1 for a certain column.  The datatype for that column was an INT and my query returned 0 results.   But, when I change the datatype for that column to varchar, and then re-run my query, I can get the results that I want.